# getting label dynamically in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, customlabel

I know that in vf i can dynamically obtain the value of a label like this :

```
<apex:outputText> {!$Label[mylabel]} </apex:outputText>
```

But this does not work in lightning :

```
    $A.get("$Label.c['customerInformation']")
```

nor this :

```
 $A.get("$Label.c[my_variable]"));
```

Has anyone been able to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i'm using a visualforce page to contain my lightning component. I evaluated my labels dynamically in my vf controller using the following method like this :

```
 public string getLabel(object o){      
    Component.Apex.OutputText output = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
    output.expressions.value = '{!$Label.' + string.valueOf(o) + '}';
    return String.valueOf(output.value);
}
```

This method use the output.expressions.value variable which can only be used in a visualforce class controller.

I processed all my required labels via this method and return a map of those label as an object to my lightning component

Comment: For anyone looking at this in 2023 - this does not work any longer. Creating dynamic Apex components is restricted to actual Visualforce controllers now.

Answer (score 4):

What i wanted to do, in fact exist on lightning, here is the code :

```
 var labelSubStr = "task_mode_today";
 var labelReference = $A.getReference("$Label.c." + labelSubStr);
 cmp.set("v.tempLabelAttr", labelReference);
 var dynamicLabel = cmp.get("v.tempLabelAttr");
```

Here is the link to the doc : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_dynamic.htm

Answer (score 0):

Doing this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm works for me.

Just try this: `console.log($A.get("$Label.namespace.labelName"));`

Comment: console.log($A.get("$Label.namespace.labelName")); doesn't work for me. Forget about the dynamic, the static one isn't working either :(

Comment: Even if you call an apex controller method that returns that label content doesn´t work for you?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_intro.htm) on the Developer Pages.

I think what you are looking for is the following:

[image: Labels In Lightning]